# grab data from a custom attribute on <img tag

Tags: jquery

Please check the javascript code bottom of code. My goal is store all data-cc attribute value as a array into my variable called "collection". I already did code bellow but something i am missing not working at all. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body>

<p id="fl">
  <img src="/images/flags/il.svg" data-cc="a" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="/images/flags/il.svg" data-cc="b" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="/images/flags/il.svg" data-cc="c" class="zastavica" />
</p>


<script>
  var collection = $(this).attr('data-cc');
  console.log(collection);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` referring to?

Comment: i dont have idea sorry i new with jquery. i though this is for this doc?

Comment: @APAD1 In his case the `window`.

Comment: @Eric I know, just trying to give them a hint as to why this wasn't working ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.each()` to loop throw the images and add the value to your array

**see snippet:**

```js
var collection = [];
$('[data-cc]').each(function() {
  collection.push($(this).attr('data-cc'));
});

console.log(collection);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fl">
  <img src="/images/flags/il.svg" data-cc="a" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="/images/flags/il.svg" data-cc="b" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="/images/flags/il.svg" data-cc="c" class="zastavica" />
</p>
```

Comment: Aw, you beat me to it. :)